# How to store and align series data with dynamic interval in Influxdb

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I have collected series data about water consumption with dynamic interval from some devices.
Data in each series may be recorded in different time interval. I would like to query and align series in fixed interval such as 5m, 10m etc.

Example raw data:

```
{ device: 1, from: 2017/01/01 00:00, to: 2017/01/01 00:13, consumption: 13 },
{ device: 1, from: 2017/01/01 00:13, to: 2017/01/01 00:20, consumption: 12 },
{ device: 1, from: 2017/01/01 00:20, to: 2017/01/01 00:28, consumption: 20 },
                              .
                              .
                              .
{ device: 2, from: 2017/01/01 00:00, to: 2017/01/01 00:06, consumption: 13 }, <--
{ device: 2, from: 2017/01/01 00:09, to: 2017/01/01 00:15, consumption: 12 }, <--Time gap between previous data may exist and can treat as zero consumption in this gap
{ device: 2, from: 2017/01/01 00:15, to: 2017/01/01 00:25, consumption: 20 },
                              .
                              .
                              .
```

You can assume that rate of consumption in particular interval is the same, i.e. the consumption per minute of `{ device: 1, from: 2017/01/01 00:00, to: 2017/01/01 00:13, consumption: 13 }` is 1 for every minute in this interval.

Expected result if fixed interval = 5m:

```
Device 1
time              consumption
----              -----------
2017-01-01T00:00Z     5
2017-01-01T05:00Z     5
2017-01-01T10:00Z     6.428571
2017-01-01T15:00Z     8.571429
2017-01-01T20:00Z     12.5
               .
               .
               .
Device 2
time              consumption
----              -----------
2017-01-01T00:00Z     10.833333
2017-01-01T05:00Z     4.166667
2017-01-01T10:00Z     10
2017-01-01T15:00Z     10
2017-01-01T20:00Z     10
               .
               .
               .
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Group by the wanted interval, aggregate results and fill values as appropriate where missing.

For example, last one hours' worth of mean consumption in 5 min intervals, gaps filled by [linear interpolation of missing values](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill).

```
SELECT mean("consumption") AS "consumption" 
FROM "Device 1", "Device 2"
WHERE time > now() - 1h
GROUP BY time(5m)
FILL(linear)
```

Assuming the measurement names are "Device 1" and "Device 2", substitute as needed.